# bijective holomorphic entire functions

Tags: holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

I want to find all entire bijective holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.
There are

- identity function

-polynomials with odd degree

Can I find an  a way more abstract function to satisfy my conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polynomials of odd degree $>1$ are not injective. The only injective entire functions are of the type $az+b$, $a\neq0$.

Comment: You man only your  function and the identity function satisfy my conditions?

Comment: The function $f(z)=z$ is of the form $az+b$ with $a=1$ and $b=0.$

Comment: I see;) This is the only function, which satisfy my conditions?